# Why does this reference equality break?

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code, filled with tests to see where the program falls apart.  The intention is that $P1 is a reference to the first element of Players, then $P1G is a reference to a member of something in $P1.  For reasons I don't understand, the program dies at 'a2a'.  As far as I can figure, assigning a value into a reference of a member should not cause the reference to be no longer equal.

$Players is an array, $P1 is an assoc array.  (all produced by PDO::fetchAll and further developing the information), and $P1 = $Players[0].

As I understand it, $A === $B means A and B variables both point to the same object, so if I assign to B, the === will become false, but if I assign to something in $B then they should remain pointing to that same object and the object is modified.  Same as most modern languages.

But, 'a2a' suggests I am misunderstanding something.  Where am I gone wrong?

```
function &pair_players0(&$Players, & $P1)
{
    $P = &$P1;
    $P1 === $Players[0] or die('a1');

    foreach ($P1['games'] as & $P1G)
    {
            $P === $P1 or die('stea');
            $P1G['opp'] = '2';
            $P1 === $Players[0] or die('a2a');
            echo $P1G['opp']. nl();
            break;
        }
    }
    $P1 === $Players[0] or die('a2');
 }
```

Perhaps the more important question is: How do I make this line not screw things up:

```
            $P1G['opp'] = '2';
```

Comment: Comment at first sight, without reading about the problem: references in PHP come quite close to a coding smell. You might want to refactor your code.

Comment: I was converting a program from another language and am quickly coming to that realization.  Not clear how to avoid references when we're dealing with a complex data structure.

Comment: Usually by converting your data structure to an object, which are always passed "by reference".

Comment: `var_dump()` values and see.

Comment: var_dump() prints the contents, does not show reference relationships

Comment: References in for loops cause a lot of problems. Get the key, as in: foreach($P1['games'] as $key=>$P1G) ... Then, you can set $P1['games'][$key] and avoid the reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. Tried it.  $P1['games'][$Key]['opp'] =  $P2['number'];  Still dies at a2a.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be run by everyone to see that it terminates on "a2a".

Comment: You're altering `$P1G` which references an element in `$P1["games"]`. That makes `$P1` no longer equal to `$Players[0]`. Whatever you're attempting, this code is very convoluted and hard to understand. Whatever it's attempting could likely be done in a different way. I've been coding in PHP for more than 15 years, and can probably count on one hand the number of times I've had no choice but to use a reference.

Comment: Thanks for your input @miken32.  My point of question is that $P1 and $Players[0] I expect both point to the same object.  So modifying something in P1 should modify that object and $Players[0] still refers to that object.  This is all very natural in C# etc.

Comment: Arrays in PHP are not compared by reference when performing a `===` equality check. The `===` equality check in PHP will check that the two values have the same value and type (specifically this operator ensures strict type checking). In particular, PHP's arrays are not compared via memory address as occurs in many other languages, but are instead compared via their contents. Objects are a different matter entirely--the `==` will compare class, properties, and values to determine equality, whereas `===` will check that the two objects are of the same instance.

Comment: Unless you've set up that reference outside the function, and both `$P1` and `$Players[0]` are objects, you can't tell if they are pointing to the same object using `===`

Comment: @Progman Creating a reproducible example is proving difficult, probably due to my misunderstanding something of what's going on.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu Edit your question to include the output of `var_dump($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);` where these variables are your arguments for your function (the `$ActiveGames` argument isn't used).

Comment: @miken32 $P1 and $Players[0] are assoc arrays.  They should be pointing to the same thing.

Comment: Arrays are not objects in PHP. They are a native scalar data type like integers or strings.

Comment: @miken32 I can accept your statement as true, but I don't know how that helps me.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu Please refer back to my earlier comment. If you compare two identical arrays using `===`, even if they were constructed separately, they will evaluate as equal. This is because PHP _does not_ compare arrays in the same manner that many other languages do. It doesn't matter that they're associative arrays--all arrays in PHP are associative, with normal arrays simply being a special case. If you want to compare two sets of data to check whether or not they are the same instance, then either wrap your data within individual objects or attach a unique ID to each entry.

Comment: @B.Fleming That answers my original question.  Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @AlanBaljeu No problem. I'll bring up an official answer shortly so that we can officially mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

As per the comments:

In other languages, array equality is typically determined by comparing the memory address of the arrays, i.e. `array1 == array2` and `array1 === array2` will only evaluate to `true` if the two arrays are the same instance of the same array in memory. Creating an identical clone of the array and comparing the clone to the original, even if the elements are identical, results in an evaluation of `false`.

In PHP, arrays are not compared in the same manner as they are in many other programming languages. Instead of checking if the two arrays are the same instance, PHP instead compares the contents of the array directly. That is, two identical arrays, even if they are different instances, will result in `array1 == array2` and `array1 === array2` evaluating to true.

In other words, arrays in PHP are compared by value, not by reference. In fact, PHP will not perform assignments of arrays by reference by default, either, and will instead create a copy of the given array.

Objects in PHP are a different matter. When using `==`, PHP will check that the classes, properties, and property values are all identical. When using `===`, PHP will check that the object's are the same instance. In other words, objects have the option of performing a comparison either by value or by reference.

With all of that in mind, you have two solutions available to you to resolve your problem of needing to compare by reference:

1. You can wrap your individual array elements within objects, which will allow `===` to perform a direct compare by reference.
2. You can add a unique ID value to each array element and compare these IDs rather than the entire arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the write-up.  That does clarify the confusion.  Of course my objective isn't comparison at all, but to have a reference change update the original.  It confused me because I was expecting === to check reference and they seemed to be the same, but evidently (now I understand) it totally doesn't.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu Yeah, it should be possible to make the references work, comparison problems aside, but it will definitely be more difficult than it should be to do things this way. If nothing else, you might consider taking a look at PHP's internal `ArrayObject` class. By wrapping your arrays with this object, you can effectively use your arrays in a similar manner to the way arrays work in most other languages. The `ArrayAccess` interface is used by this class and allows accessing the object's data as if it were an array. Just note that array functions won't work on these objects.

Comment: I seem to be making progress.  Converted the game assoc into a class/object.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck!